# How to detect 3:4 tablets values

Tags: android, tablet, screen-resolution

I have two designs for tablets, first for 16:10 tablets and second for 3:4 tablets.
I can detect tablets values with `values-sw600dp` and `values-sw720dp` but it can be 16:10 and 3:4.

How can I detect only 3:4 tablets values ?